# how to substrac two fields from the same column in sql server using php calculation

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

i have SQL server database , and I'm using php to connect to it and using queries.
i've read two records from the database for one employee. and i need them to calculate the works hours to the employee. but i couldn't figure how to select to fields from the same column to the same employee. as in the picture:

E003   2014-03-17    08:10:12    2221

E003   2014-03-17    10:05:02    2222

E003   2014-03-17    12:15:20    2221

E003   2014-03-17    15:03:30    2222

the 2221 is the entring door, and the 2222 is the exit door. i want to select the time from the 2222 and substract them to have the works hours for the employee. can you help me with that pleas, this is my code:

```
<?php

$host = "servername\instancename";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"AccessCard", "UID"=>"", "PWD"=>"");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $host, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
echo "</br>"; 

/**********************************************/
$FRISTsql = "SELECT [EmpID],[DATE],[TIME],[OBJECT] FROM [AccessCard].[dbo].[TimeAtt] WHERE [EmpID]='E003'";
$Fstmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $FRISTsql );
if( $Fstmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
while( $Frow = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $Fstmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

      $R1 = $Frow['EmpID'];
      $R2 = $Frow['DATE']->format('Y-m-d');
      $R3 = $Frow['TIME']->format('H:i:s');
      $R4 = $Frow['OBJECT'];

     ECHO $R1." &nbsp&nbsp";
     ECHO $R2." &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";
     ECHO $R3." &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";
     ECHO $R4."</BR> ";

}
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $Fstmt);
```

Comment: Cant see the picture, can you post your echo results as well. One easy way is to check for the same date (between records) and subtract the time to calculate the working hours.

Comment: this is the result picture: http://im54.gulfup.com/ai4Fo.png .. i can do that but in the data base i have 4000 row, so it wont work and be efficient if i enter the for each employee, if that what you mean, but if not would you show me what did you mean pleas?

Comment: The link is blocked for me, so i cant see the picture. But i suggest you may have to do this with the query itself.

Comment: http://www.gulfup.com/?EDIJ39 try this one, i could do it with query, but my supervisor want it by php.

Comment: That is blocked too. Can you insert it inside your post.

Comment: i copied it in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the given results you can do the following. But extending for 4000 records, you may need to look for some query manipulation.

Plz, check the date comparison part as i may not be correct by the PHP syntax and function. But this can be used as a general concept.

```
 <?php

    $host = "servername\instancename";
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"AccessCard", "UID"=>"", "PWD"=>"");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $host, $connectionInfo);
    if( $conn === false ) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    echo "</br>"; 

    /**********************************************/
    $FRISTsql = "SELECT [EmpID],[DATE],[TIME],[OBJECT] FROM [AccessCard].[dbo].[TimeAtt] WHERE [EmpID]='E003' order by [DATE],[TIME]";
    $Fstmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $FRISTsql );
    if( $Fstmt === false) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
    }
else {
$enterTime; $exitTime;
    while( $Frow = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $Fstmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

          $R1 = $Frow['EmpID'];
          $R2 = $Frow['DATE']->format('Y-m-d');
          $R3 = $Frow['TIME']->format('H:i:s');
          $R4 = $Frow['OBJECT'];
    if($enterTime == null && $R4 == 2001)
    {
             $enterTime = $R3;
     }
    if($exitTime == null && $R4 == 2002)
    {
             $exitTime = $R3;
     }
    else if($R3 < $enterTime && $R4 == 2001)
    {
            $enterTime = $R3;
    }
    else if($R3 > $exitTime && $R4 == 2002)
    {
            $exitTime = $R3;
    }
         ECHO $R1." &nbsp&nbsp";
         ECHO $R2." &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";
         ECHO $R3." &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp";
         ECHO $R4."</BR> ";

    }
ECHO "User:".$R1." for date".$R2." worked for ".($exitTime -  $enterTime);
}
    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $Fstmt);
```